# Could there be merge conflicts with to simultan triggered Pull Requests in Azure DevOps and how to handle them?

Tags: git, azure, python-requests, devops, pull

i started working with Azure DevOps a few months ago. I have one question regarding the Pull Requests in Azure DevOps:

If for example 2 developers are working on the same topic and both changes would yield to a merge conflict. Each developers created its own remote branch and the developers would create a pull request simultaneously on master.

Is Azure DevOps detecting this merge conflict and showing it by first in first out principle?

And the more important question: What is the best practise for preventing such situations?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that each branch individually conflicts with `master` : this is detected as soon as the Pull Request is opened, and would appear on both PRs.

If you mean that each branch would conflict with the other : this is not highlighted until one of the PRs is merged into `master`.
The rule is "first merged, first served".